# How to find the coordinates of the rectangle after turning the javafx shape

Tags: java, javafx

I draw a rectangle with coordinates (x = 100, y = 100, width = 200, height = 100). Then I turn the shape of this rectangle around the center.

```
this.rotation.addListener((obs, old, fresh) -> {
    Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
    rotate.setAngle((double) fresh - (double) old);
    rotate.setPivotX(x.getValue().doubleValue() + (width.getValue().doubleValue() / 2));
    rotate.setPivotY(y.getValue().doubleValue() + (height.getValue().doubleValue() / 2));
    shape.getTransforms().addAll(rotate);
});
```

How now to find out the coordinates of shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `localToParent` method to transform a point from the coordinate system of the `Rectangle` to the coordinate system of the parent.

```
Point2D topLeftInParent = shape.localToParent(shape.getX(), shape.getY());
```

If you simply need the x/y range in the parent where the `Rectangle` is displayed, you could also use `getBoundsInParent`:

```
Bounds parentBounds = shape.getBoundsInParent();
```

BTW: I do not recommend adding a new transform on every change. Instead I recommend adjusting the existing rotation:

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate(0, shape.getX() + shape.getWidth()/2, shape.getX() + shape.getHeight()/2);
shape.getTransforms().add(rotate);
rotate.angleProperty().bind(this.rotation);
```